# retrieve data with Contains id

Tags: linq, ravendb

Raven DB gave me this message

> Method not supported: Contains

for this code :

```
 using (var d = DataLayer.RavenDB.d.OpenSession())
    {
      foos = d.Query<Foo>().Where(foo => ids.Contains(foo.Id)).Skip(i * 10).Take(10).ToList();
    }
```

how can I retrieve my list `foos` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to load the documents based on the list of ids, go the solution suggested by Matt, performance wise Load() is the best approach.

but if you still wants to get it using Query (using some where contiions) change the code like this

```
using (var d = DataLayer.RavenDB.d.OpenSession())
    {
         foos = d.Query<Foo>()
                 .Where(foo => foo.Id.In<string>(ids))
                 .Skip(i * 10)
                 .Take(10).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to query multiple documents by id.  Querying by Id is not recommended in Raven.  Load them instead.  There is an overload that takes multiple Ids.

```
foos = session.Load<Foo>(ids);
```

If this was some other property rather than Id, you would use `item.In(list)` rather than `list.Contains(item)`.

Comment: do you know if it will filter the unwanted element in the query of after his query?

Comment: query filtering happens server-side, if that's what you are asking.